# Best approach to populate a JSP dropdown with fixed/static list of values

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu

I have a fixed list of 20+ values to be populated in a dropdown. The set of values are always going to remain the same, no future scope of modifications, additions or deletions.

Listing each of them as  in JSP is making the page look cluttered.

Or is it better reading it as a comma-separated string from a properties file and then iterating to populate the dropdown.

Or any other suggestions?
**What will be the best approach to populate such a dropdown in JSP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a framework such as Struts or Spring MVC?

The general approach to do this is to declare and initalise the array in your class file and create getters and setters.

Then in your JSP iterate through the array and add options to your dropdown dynamically.

For example

Create array with predefined values

```
String[] myArray = {"option1", "option2", "option3"};
```

Create getters and setters

```
public String[] getMyArray() {
    return myArray;
}
public void setMyArray(String[] myArray) {
    this.myArray = myArray;
}
```

Then create select dropdown and iterate through your array, you can use Struts2 tags like this

```
<select>
    <s:iterator value="myArray">
        <option value="<s:property/>"><s:property/></option> <!-- This prints out current value of the iterator -->
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

Google struts2 iterator for more examples